Is there a function to retrieve the LOC added or deleted in github's PR instead of manually counting them from the files?
I got a code that will automatically reads Github PRs and shows the lines of code added or deleted that works.
However, I have to manually traverse through all the files in each PR to tabulate the LOC for each.
from github import Github

# Replace with your personal access token
github_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

# Replace with your desired repository information
org_name = "your_organization"
repo_name = "your_repository"

# Create a GitHub object with your access token
g = Github(github_token)

# Get the repository object
repo = g.get_repo(f"{org_name}/{repo_name}")

# Get all pull requests (adjust state and number parameters as needed)
pull_requests = repo.get_pulls(state="open", sort="created", direction="desc")

# Iterate through each pull request
for pull_request in pull_requests:

  # Initialize counters for added and deleted lines
  additions = 0
  deletions = 0

  # Get the pull request files
  files = pull_request.get_files()

  # Iterate through each file in the pull request
  for file in files:

    # Extract additions and deletions from the file object
    additions += file.additions
    deletions += file.deletions

  # Print information about the pull request with line counts
  print(f"** PR #{pull_request.number}: {pull_request.title} **")
  print(f"URL: {pull_request.html_url}")
  print(f"Added lines: {additions}")
  print(f"Deleted lines: {deletions}")
  print(f"Total lines changed: {additions + deletions}\n")

Is the an easier way (a function?) to get that in PyGithub or other method?

Take a look at Github REST API get-a-pull-request. The response has additions, deletions and changed_files. Python Github should have a corresponding method to retrieve the same response so that you don't have to iterate over the files and do the calculation by yourself.
